# when use onchange event then delete record information of deleted record set for other record

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a table of items and each item have base_price and I have an input and can change the count of items and then total_price changed.
All things are ok. But when I change the amount of input then decide to remove it the amount of input and the total_price set for other item.
When I don't change the input all things right work but when I change the input get this problem.

```
<input onChange={e => this.changeTotalPrice(e, service)} type="number" defaultValue="1" min="1"/>

<td style={{fontWeight: 'bold', color: '#000'}}>
  <span id={`totalPrice-${service.id}`} className="totalPrices"> 
    {service.price}
  </span></td>

changeTotalPrice(e, service) {
  let totalPriceTag = document.getElementById(`totalPrice-${service.id}`);
  let totalPrice = e.target.value * service.price;
  totalPriceTag.innerText = totalPrice;
}
```

Comment: mutating DOM directly goes against [Thinking in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html), have you tried to put the correct value into state and modify by `this.setState({service})`? in any case, what do you mean by `this problem` please - what is the expected vs actual outcome?

Comment: @aprillion I expected the row deleted completely but the input[number] and total_price didn't delete and set for other item . I can't use state for this sample because I have many dynamic item

Comment: since you don't delete anything in the code provided, I don't understand how you expect something to be deleted ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ unless you provide [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to explicitly say what is the problem, the expected outcome for some sample input data + the code you tried that is relevant to the problem

Comment: if you really cannot use props or state, then you should not use React (but 99%, it is possible to use it just fine - if you explain the problem)